# Add custom lookup field in VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I want to create a VF page that displays a Custom Object's Lookup field.
I create the object in my apex controller class using the new keyword and would like to add a lookup field to write another object into it like this:

```
<apex:inputField id="mapConstructie" value="{!project_element.Constructie__c}"/>
```

Controller:

> 

```
public Project_Element__c project_element { get; set; }
 project_element    = new Project_Element__c( project__c =
currentProject.Id );    
public void addEditProjectElement( )
     {
        try
          {     

             insert project_element;
             project_elements_map.put( project_element.Id, new ProjectElementDTO( project_element, project_elements_map.size( ) ) );
         } catch( Exception exc )
         {
              ApexPages.addMessages( exc );
          }
      }
```

Where Constructie__c is a lookup field.
If I now do an insert, project_element.Constructie__c is empty.
How can I make sure that project_element.Constructie__c is filled using the VF code above?

Comment: Adding required="true" to the apex:inputField should be a simple solution.

Comment: I don't mean that the user should be forced to add a value; I mean that when they do, the field in the project_element object should be filled. Right now, if I do a insert project_element; it's Constructie__c field is empty, even when I just added a value using the lookup field.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your controller code then; the ID of the object would normally be automatically set in the project_element reference when the form is submitted.

Comment: OK, I edited it, so my controller is in there now too. It's a very long file so I only added parts of it here.

Comment: Bit hard to tell, but as long as project_element is only initialised once (e.g. in the constructor) and you are using e.g. an apex:commandButton to post the form, I can't see anything wrong. Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: do you have <apex:pagemessages/> on your VF page, this will show exceptions and are you sure if the project_element is getting inserted?

Comment: Can we see more of the VF page, please? Specifically, the `<apex:form` and `<apex:commandbutton>` tags.